# How do I add dropdownlist in gridview which can be used to modify a sql database in asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a sql database with three columns including id, Name and country. I have a limited number of countries in the database. I need to open the database in asp.net using a gridview with three columns including edit/delete buttons, name and country. When the user select the edit button, the name was shown as text box while the countries was listed in a dropdownlist in gridview. The user can edit both columns and the modification was added to sql database. How can I do that in asp.net?

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" Visible="false" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" SortExpression="Country" Visible="false" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country ">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NameCountryConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Specs] WHERE [Id] = @Id" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Specs] ([Id], [Name], [Country]) VALUES (@Id, @Name, @Country)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Specs]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Specs] SET [Name] = @Name, [Country] = @Country WHERE [Id] = @Id">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Country" Type="String" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Country" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
                </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Please do write what you have done so far. Put some code in reference of your question or some link. You can visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to how to ask good question.

Comment: I have added the asp code in the question field.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use TemplateField  in grid view:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DropDownList ">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Put your code here...

Comment: Please let me know how to apply new selection of dropdownlist in the sql database after I modify the gridview.